# Prestashop - Sobreescribir un controlador de la zona admin desde un módulo

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7

estoy desarrollando un módulo de pasarela de pago y me encuentro con la necesidad de intentar sobreescribir el controller de la zona admin para mostrar información específica de esta pasarela de pago en la vista de detalle del pedido.

Concretamente el controller que quiero sobreescribir es OrderController (Namespace PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\Sell\Order).

No encuentro la manera de hacer ese override desde el módulo. He buscado en diferentes post y he probado lo siguiente:

Crear un controller nuevo llamado **OrderController** que extienda del anteriormente descrito y situarlo en *mymodule/override/controllers/admin/OrderController.php* y no consigo hacerlo funcionar.

Lo que si ha sido factible ha sido hacer override de vistas ubicandolas en *views/templates/admin/...*

**¿Alguien puede ayudarme?**

Answer (score 0):

Colocar el controller en el módulo sirve para que cuando se instale el módulo, se aplique tu override dentro del lugar correcto para ello, que es en `override/controllers/admin/OrderController.php`, y si ya existe tratará de mezclar tu personalización con el código ya existente.

Pero creo que el verdadero problema está en el controller que estás tratando de sobrescribir. Resulta que desde hace cierta versión de la rama 1.7 de PrestaShop **ya no se usa ese controlador** (el de pedidos), porque ese apartado ya está completamente pasado a Symfony, y, por tanto, si necesitas hacer personalizaciones tienes que hacerlo de otra forma, aunque te advierto que no hay la misma facilidad que antes.

Yo me he encontrado con ese problema, y por ejemplo para personalizar el listado de pedidos la mejor solución ha sido crear un listado aparte del nativo de PrestaShop, como un admin controller de un módulo. Si necesitas personalizar algo en la ficha de un pedido, puedes tirar de hooks, y usar javascript para hacer retoques. Hay que usar la imaginación.